# gksudo with cool GNOME Shell integration

Tags: gnome, authentication, command-line, gksu

What's the command for executing this "gksudo" (or whatever it is) window from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>?

[image: cool gksudo]

Comment: I cannot understand what are you asking. Can you clarify, plase?

Comment: WoW, very good picture i love transparent things

Comment: That window doesn't look like quite the same thing I get on my stock GNOME Shell install. Perhaps it has been themed, in which case a link to the theme used in an answer below would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 10):

That cool window in GNOME Shell is only displayed for applications that use PolicyKit. For example, to trigger this window for Synaptic, run this in a terminal:

```
pkexec synaptic
```

You can't use `pkexec` for all applications but only for those that have a `pkexec` policy file under `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/`.

Comment: However, it doesn't work when you launch it from Alt+F2

Comment: then why all programs not using PolicyKit, and is it work for unity also???

Comment: Yes, it works under Unity (but it looks different).

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use the command `gksu-polkit`. It largely behaves the same as gksudo, but taps into the policykit framework. To use it install the package 'gksu-polkit'.